# Relative import in Python package does not seem to work

Tags: python, python-3.x, package

I have a package which is structured as follows:

```
mypackage/
  util/
    __init__.py
    a.py
  b.py
  __init__.py
  setup.py
```

The `__init__.py` files are empty. In `b.py` there is an import of `util/a.py`:

```
from .util import a
```

The tests included with the package run fine. However, when I install the package and try to use it in another project with `from mypackage import b`, I get:

```
File [...] , in <module>
    from mypackage import b
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mypackage-0.0.1-py3.7.egg/mypackage/b.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .util import a
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mypackage.util'
```

### Edit 1

`setup.py` looks like this:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name="mypackage",
      version="0.0.1",
      description="My package",
      packages=["mypackage"])
```

Comment: How are you installing the package? Can you include your `setup` script?

Comment: @Brian Edited my post, installing with `python3 setup.py install`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to include that sub-package in the call to [`setup`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#using-find-packages) otherwise it won't be installed:

```
setup(
    ...
    packages=[
        'mypackage',
        'mypackage.util',
    ]
)
```

You can also use [`setuptools.find_packages`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#using-find-packages) in order to automatize this process:

```
from setuptools import find_packages

setup(..., packages=find_packages())
```